# Windows: how to get IPv6 address for development purposes?

Tags: windows, ip, ipv6

My Internet provider gives me an IP v4 address.
For development purposes, I need to make tests and write scripts for IPv6 (IP banning, IP detecting..)

How can I simulate/get a IP V6 on Windows for my tests?
(some VPN ?)

Comment: This question doesn't fit this forum, but you should research 6rd, if your ISP supports it, or a 6in4 tunnel like the service provided by Hurricane Electric and others.

Comment: You could always use ULA within your own network for development and testing. Of the `fc00::/7` ULA range, you are allowed to use networks in the `fd00:/8` range, but you are required to randomly select the next 40 bits of the prefix in order to give you a good chance of generating a globally unique prefix. You cannot use ULA address on the public Internet, but it will work for development and testing in a lab.

Comment: You should also complain to your ISP. It's 2020 already!